# Partition Move/Resize

Tags: partitioning

I have a windows8/ubuntu 13.04 dualboot system. My ubuntu is installed between two NTFS partitions. Now I'm running out of space, so I want to increase Ubuntu Partition.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

**Note:  When dealing with partitions, always make sure that you have a current backup, just in case.**

You need to boot either from the Ubuntu LiveCD, or the [Gparted LiveCD](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php).  Once you boot up bring up Gparted, and make sure that either `/dev/sda2` or `/dev/sda4` are Un-mounted.  You don't have to use both of them, just choose whichever one you want to use.

[image]

Once un-mounted, just right click on the partition that you choose, and click on Resize/Move, and shrink it down to what you need.  Once that's done, and applied.

Then choose `/dev/sda5`, right click, and again choose Resize/Move, and extend the partition with the newly created available space.

[image]

**Note:  When dealing with partitions, always make sure that you have a current backup, just in case.**

Comment: If expanding into the unallocated you have to move the start of the extended partition left so the unallocated is inside the extended partition. Then you can move sda5 left. Moving data left can be a slow process as all data must be moved, do not interrupt as any interruption will corrupt partition. Or why to have good backups.

Comment: @oldfred `/dev/sda2` has no data, the OP shows that in the image.

Answer (score 0):

You need to boot your system in rescue mode or you can use Live ISO. I had similar issue but using [Parted Magic OS](http://partedmagic.com/doku.php#.UgDe46xRcmY), I have solved my issue.

So refer [this](http://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual&lang=C#gparted-resize-partition) page for Re-size Partitions.